# AngularFire & Ionic - No data form is transmitted to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I use Ionic and AngularFire for make my app, but I have a (new) problem:
My data form are empty ! We can see just the fiels in my DataBase Firebase. 
How do I do to retrieve the form data entered by the user in the Firebase database?

The issue in image :

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/238594event.png

This is my HTML :

```
<form ng-submit="submitEvent(event)">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Nom de l'événement</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="event.nameid">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label"><i class="icon ion-ios-information"></i> Description</span>
    <br><textarea ng-model="event.descriptionid"></textarea>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Adresse</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="event.addressid">
  </label>

  <button class="button" type="submit" value="Add Event" id="success-btn-create"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button></form>
```

This is my Controller JS :

```
myApp.controller('Step1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Event', 'Auth', '$rootScope', '$state', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, Event, Auth, $rootScope, $state, $firebaseArray) {

  $scope.submitEvent = function(event) {

    var nameid = $scope.nameid;
    var eventRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events");
    eventRef.push($scope.event);
    $scope.event = {nameid: '', descriptionid: '', adressid: ''};

  }

  $scope.deleteEvent = function(index) {
    $scope.events.splice(index , 1);
  }


}])
```

This is my Service JS :

```
myApp.factory("Event", ["$firebaseArray", function($firebaseArray) {
var eventRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events/');
  return $firebaseArray(eventRef);
}]);
```

An optional question : How to recover a name of the organizer ? He is logged with Facebook ...

Thanks all folks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your controller:

```
$scope.submitEvent = function(event) {

   Event.add(event).then(function (data){ 
      $scope.event = {nameid: null, descriptionid: null, adressid: null};
     });
  }
```

you can also reorganize your service as follows:

```
myApp.factory("Event", ["$firebaseArray", function($firebaseArray) {
  var eventRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events/');
  return {
         get: function (){
                return $firebaseArray(eventRef);
              }
            ,
        add: function (event){
          var eventInfo = $firebaseArray(eventRef);
          return eventInfo.$add(event);
              }
       }
}]);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Ali for your time. But I add "$scope.event= Event.get();" in my controller and reorganized my service and always nothing happen in Database ...
It's like this :
$scope.submitEvent = function(event) {

    var eventRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events");
    eventRef.push($scope.event);
    $scope.event = Event.get();
    $scope.event = {nameid: '', descriptionid: '', adressid: '''};
    
  }
I have make mistake ?
Best regards.

Comment: I thought your problem was about retrieving data, not saving it.. I've updated my answer accordingly.. let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, but I have this : Error: $firebase has been removed. You may instantiate $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject directly now. For simple write operations, just use the Firebase ref directly. See the AngularFire 1.0.0 changelog for details: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html

Comment: that's bcuz you're having a newer version of firebase than the one I have, the new fix should work.

Comment: Alala , another problem lol : "TypeError: eventInfo.$push is not a function
    at Object.add (http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:17:28)
    at Scope.$scope.submitEvent (http://localhost:8100/js/app.js:115:11)" ... An idea ? Thanks a lot for your time ..

Comment: I noticed some changes in the new version of angularfire... try eventInfo.$add instead of .$push. let me know if it worked.

Comment: It's WORK !!! Thanks you Ali you save my day !!! :D
I have one more question : How can I get the name, id and picture of the user who created the event? It is connected only with Facebook.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct answer so any one with the same problem could benefit from it... let me understand your question, do you want to integrate with facebook and get the user name and profile pic ... etc?

Comment: here is really good docs that will walk you through Facebook authentication, and you will find all you need in authData object: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html .. just follow the doc.

Comment: The user is already authentificated in my App, he's create an event, I want to know who have create the event for display his name and his picture in the event post.

Comment: you may pass "user_id" as a parameter of add function along with the event obj. and change you refEvent to something like this:
var eventRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events/' + user_id);

in this case the event will be added under Events-> user_id

Comment: or you can add the user_id  as part of the event object like:
{nameid: xxx, descriptionid: xxxx, adressid: xx, createdBy: userId};

Comment: Thanks you, I have this issue : Date and Time don't display in database. Just text and number work ...